# Проблема с кодировкой русских символов PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

Я сделал приложение на Spring Boot с регистрацией, вроде бы ничего сложного, всё работает как надо кроме того что имя и фамилия пользователя сохраняется как-то поломано

> &#1053 &#1086 &#1074 &#1080 &#1082 &#1086 &#1074

С чем связанна эта проблема? Английские буквы и символы сохранились как надо, но вот русские нет.

То что я вам скинул, не полная версия этой ошибки. Я её немного отредактировал чтобы вы могли понять в чём дело, но вот если я скину полную версию вы увидите обычную фамилию и никаких проблем, но не в базе данных:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена, точную причину проблем я так и не понял, но нашёл решение

Я изменил код своего контроллера с:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path = "/")
public class WebController {
```

на:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path = "/", produces = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8")
public class WebController {
```

Как вы поняли, решение это добавление данное строки в @RequestMapping

```
produces = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8"
```

Спасибо всем за внимание и всем тем кто пытался помочь, текст отображается и сохраняется корректно, всем удачи и добра!

**Обновление 29 октября, 2023 года**

Забыл упомянуть ещё кое что очень важное, в application.properties, вставьте вот это:

```
server.servlet.encoding.charset=UTF-8
server.servlet.encoding.force=true
```

После этого моя проблема решается.